# How can I update multiple crystal reports at one time?

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to make changes to multiple reports at one time, e.g., add the same logo to all of the report headers, etc., but I don't want to open each report manually and make the changes as there are many of them.  Is there some way to script this?  I have not found anything in the designer (CR2008) that would do this, but if I am missing something, I would greatly appreciate a point in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are launching your reports from software you control, then I believe you can add code in the software to take advantage of Crystal's API and dynamically load the logo into a control.  Alternatively, I think there might be an option to have reports reload their subreports every time you use them.  Not positive about that, but if there is then you could add your logo as a subreport and turn this option on, and then you'd only need to update the subreport.

Comment: The reports are launched from a proprietary 3rd party application that I can't control.  I don't think the CR engine is built into the application, so it might be possible to write something that would use the engine separately.  I like the subreport idea.  That would be very good for making changes.  However, I don't want to manually add the subreport to each report.  I would like to automate the process of adding the subreport to each report.

Comment: Well even if you don't have access to the application that launches the report to do it at runtime, that doesn't prevent you from writing your own application to open the report files, change the title logo, and then save it (or if you prefer, add a subreport so that you can just edit that in the future).

Comment: I thought maybe there was some built-in tools like VBA for Office or AutoCAD, but I can't find anything like that.  However, I have just found out about crpe32.dll and the many other things you apparently need to run CR.  Although, I think many of them are only needed if you want to deploy an application, and I don't want to do that.  Looks like I have alot to learn! Thanks for your Help!

Comment: Well, if you do .net programming then you can just install Visual Studio and it comes with an embedded version of Crystal Reports that you can use.

Answer (score 1):

There was a product called .rpt Inspector from Software Forces that allowed this, unfortunately it would only run on Windows XP, it is being trialled as a Beta as an online product you could subscribe to try it.
Check
http://www.softwareforces.com/

Answer (score 0):

.rpt Inspector Professional Suite and .rpt Inspector Enterprise Suite both allow you to do that but they don't support Windows 7, 8.x, or 10. And require 32bit. So you need to either run it in a virtual machine like (Windows XP Mode of Windows 7) or something like virtualbox (free) or vmware. There is a trial (https://www.softwareforces.com/Download) but neither is free. Both are also in end of life.

The replacement, a free tool, .rpt Inspector Online (https://rpt.inspector.tools) may be a great option. It doesn't have the same issues / limitations. So you can document and make changes to multiple reports (i.e. change data source, edit formulas, edit parameter default values, etc.)